# Transform Graph Cycle to rectangle area

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

Having the cycle like the image below

a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h

a-h overlapping b,g but w/o node/connection

d-e overlapping c,e but w/o node/connection

[image]

Compute the area of this cycle.

So effectively it is area of b-c-f-g.

Or how to transform a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h cycle into b-c-f-g cycle?

Not looking for ready solution more for directions.

Comment: Is it plain geometry or does each node has spacial coordinate dimensions?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto All the nodes/points have specific coordinates. Vertical vertices exactly overlaps themselves and b, g ,c ,f nodes. Why I confusing points and nodes is coz it is black-white graphic transformed into mathematical graph :)

Comment: Since you have explicit information about nodes coordinates, you can directly calculate the area from formula "width*height". In this case, we deal with Euclidean coordinates, it means, (f.x-g.x)(c.y-f.y)

Comment: Yes, it is the first approach but I think it is possible to be done with some graph algorithms - like creating new nodes where b, c, f, g are and then cut-off hanging vertices... a-b, g-h, f-e, c-d

Comment: Of course, you can kill an ant with a tank. But don't you think it is even smarter to walk around it?

Comment: a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h is not a cycle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it should be drawn in 3D or using dashed lines to see it is - directly connected a-h is also connected by a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h but not by a-b-g-h.

Comment: Cycle is term of graph theory, area is term of geometry. What is area of a cycle?

Comment: I can understand it like following. There is closed polygonal line ABCDEFGHA in 3D and we need to find area of interior of its projection. abcdefgha is projection of ABCDEFGHA, then we need to find area of its interior. This interior is the same as interior of bcfg, then we need to find area of interior of bcfg. But how it all is related to graph theory?

Comment: For not self-crossing polygonal line one can find area of its interior using "formula of area of polygon by coordinates". In this case abcdefgha can be considered as limit of not self-crossing polygonal line, then area of its interior can be calculated using the same formula. 

To eliminate points a and h one can use following argumentation. Using coordinates one can show that a and h do not lie in the same semiplane with respect to bg as points c,d,e,f, then S=S(abgha)+S(bcdefgb). Using coordinates one can show that S(abgha)=0, then one can exclude a and h without changing S.

Comment: I took "a-h overlapping b,g but w/o node/connection" to mean there was no a-h connection, but now you say a-h is directly connected. So why not draw in all the connections that are there?